# if statement compare places

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

We are working on another game and we have several answers to a question. Now the problem is that I need to compare the place of the whale to the place of a fish with the answer.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```
var Keys = {
    left: 37,
    right: 39,
    up:38,
    down:40
}

function Start(){    
    $("#start").hide();
    alert ("test start weg");
    Opdr1();
}

$(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.which){
            case Keys.right:
                $("#whale").css("left", "+=10px");
                $("#whale").attr("src", "pacman-right.png");
                break;
            case Keys.left:
                $("#whale").css("left", "-=10px");
                $("#whale").attr("src", "pacman-left.png");
                break;
            case Keys.up:
                $("#whale").css("top", "-=10px");
                break;
            case Keys.down:
                $("#whale").css("top", "+=10px");
                break;
        }
    });
});

function Opdr1(){
    $(".bubbel").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".vis1-1").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".vis2-1").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".vis3-1").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".vis4-1").css("visibility", "visible");

        //if the whale's css left and top is the same as the left and top of the vis-1 then { }

        if($("#whale").css("left") == ("left") {
            alert('vis-1 fout');
        }
        if($("#whale").css('left') == (".vis2-1").css('left')) {
            alert('vis-2 fout');
        }
        if($("#whale").css('left') == (".vis3-1").css('left')) {
            alert('vis-3 fout');
        }
        if($("#whale").css('left') == (".vis4-1").css('left')) {
            alert('vis-4 fout');
        }

}
```

Comment: What answer? Could you not compare the values of [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) from the two elements?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of the two objects

For example,

```
if ( $("#whale").offset().top == $(".vis-1").offset().top )
{
}
```

similarly

```
if ( $("#whale").offset().left == $(".vis-1").offset().left )
{
}
```